Dismiss keyboard not calling on entire VStack
Implementing a dismiss keyboard function as an extension of View, and then calling in my view. It doesn't seem to work too well. It seems like you have to click at very specific places to get the keyboard to dismiss and I mean like weird places (top right of the screen, or just above the textfield, BUT won't dismiss it right next to or under the Textfield). It seems to not be applying to the entire VStack? I'm not sure.
Here is my code:
Dismiss keyboard function:
extension View {
    func dismissKeyboardForView() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}

//
//  Pressure&DensityView.swift
//  FlightBuddyApp
//
//  Created by Yehuda Lelah on 4/12/24.
//

import SwiftUI

struct Pressure_DensityView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: SharedData
    @EnvironmentObject private var modelToPass: SharedData
    
    // var formatter = NumberFormatter() // For formatting result strings
    
    @State var altimSet = "3"
    @State var elev = "3"
    
    @State var altimSetPlaceholder = "Current Altimiter Setting"
    @State var elevPlaceholder = "Field Elevation"
    
    @State var oatSet = "3"
    @State var isaSet = "3"
    
    @State var oatSetPlaceholder = "Current OAT"
    @State var isaSetPlaceholder = "ISA"
    
    // pa & da
    @State var pressurealtitude = 0
    @State var densityaltitude = 0
    
    var anyOfMultiple: [String] {[
        altimSet, elev, oatSet, isaSet
    ]}
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            
            VStack {
                Text("Pressure Altitude: \(pressurealtitude)")
                Text("Density Alitude: \(densityaltitude)")
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100)
            .font(.title3)
            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            
            // Stack to handle Altim and FE
            VStack {
                TextField(altimSetPlaceholder, text: $altimSet)
                Divider()
                TextField(elevPlaceholder, text: $elev)
                
                Divider()
                
                TextField(oatSetPlaceholder, text: $oatSet) // oat
                Divider()
                TextField(isaSetPlaceholder, text: $isaSet) // isa
            }
            .font(.title2)
            .fontDesign(.monospaced)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding()
            
            .task {
                if !model.airportName.isEmpty { // if not empty...

                    
                    
                    // .. set placeholder text of texfield to current from json pull
                    altimSetPlaceholder = String(model.airportAltimSetting)
                    elevPlaceholder = String(model.airportFieldElev)
                    oatSetPlaceholder = String(model.airportTemp)
                    
                    print("json field \(model.airportFieldElev)")
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: anyOfMultiple) {
                // disabledButtonDueToEmptyTextFields()
            }

            
            Button {
                guard model.airportAltimSetting.description.isEmpty == false else { return }
                guard model.airportFieldElev.description.isEmpty == false else { return }
                
                
                if (altimSet != "" && elev != "") {
                    // calc pa
                    pressurealtitude = pressureAltitude((altimSet as NSString).doubleValue, (elev as NSString).integerValue)
                } else {
                    // calc pa
                    pressurealtitude = pressureAltitude(model.airportAltimSetting, model.airportFieldElev)
                }
                
                
                // calc for isa
                let isa = calculateISA(pressurealtitude)
                isaSet = String(isa)
                
                if (oatSet != "") {
                    // calc da
                    densityaltitude = densityAltitude((oatSet as NSString).integerValue, isa, pressureAltitude: pressurealtitude)
                } else {
                    // calc da
                    densityaltitude = densityAltitude(Int(model.airportTemp), isa, pressureAltitude: pressurealtitude)
                }
    
                /// Pass calculated airport press & dens altitudes
                modelToPass.airportPressureAltitude = pressurealtitude
                modelToPass.airportDensityAltitude = densityaltitude
                
                
            } label: {
                Text("Calculate")
            }
            .buttonStyle(CalculateButton())
        }
        .onAppear() {
            
            disabledButtonDueToEmptyTextFields() // will change color of button if any textfields are empty that are required for the calculations
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            self.dismissKeyboardForView()
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button {
                Task {
                    // reset / reload
                    resetPADAValues()
                    disabledButtonDueToEmptyTextFields()
                }
            } label: { Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")}
            .buttonStyle(ResetFieldsForCalculateButton())
            
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    /// Pressure Altitude
    func pressureAltitude(_ currentAltimSetting: Double, _ fieldElevation: Int) -> Int {
        /** PA = [(29.92 - current) * 1000] + FE  **/
        print("current altim: \(currentAltimSetting)")
        print("current field: \(fieldElevation)")
        let pa = ((29.92 - currentAltimSetting) * 1000) + Double(fieldElevation)
        let paInt = Int(pa)
        return paInt
    }
    
    /// Density Altitude
    func densityAltitude(_ oat: Int, _ isa: Int, pressureAltitude: Int) -> Int {
        /** DA = [(OAT - ISA) * 120] + PA **/
        let da = ((oat - isa) * 120) + pressureAltitude
        let daInt = Int(da)
        return daInt
    }
    
    /// ISA Calc
    /// automatically calcs current isa based on airport pressure altitude
    func calculateISA(_ pressureAltitude: Int) -> Int {
        var startAlt: Int = 1000
        var isa: Int = 0
        var isaMath: Int = 15
        
        for _ in 1...10 {
            if pressureAltitude < startAlt {
                isa = isaMath
                if (startAlt - pressureAltitude) < 300 {
                    isa -= 2
                }
            } else {
                startAlt += 1000
                isaMath -= 2
            }
        }
        
        return isa
    }
    
    func resetPADAValues() {
        altimSet = ""
        elev = ""
        oatSet = ""
        isaSet = ""
        pressurealtitude = 0
        densityaltitude = 0
    }
    
    func disabledButtonDueToEmptyTextFields() {
        model.areTFEmpty = true // reset
        if (altimSet.isEmpty || elev.isEmpty || oatSet.isEmpty || isaSet.isEmpty && (arePlaceholdersEmpty() == true)) {
            modelToPass.areTFEmpty = true
        } else {
            modelToPass.areTFEmpty = false
        }
    }
    
    func arePlaceholdersEmpty() -> Bool {
        /*
          are they empty?
         yes: true
         no: false
         */
        var isTrue = Bool()
        if ( (altimSetPlaceholder != "Current Altimiter Setting" || altimSetPlaceholder != "")
            || (elevPlaceholder != "Field Elevation" || elevPlaceholder != "")
            || (oatSetPlaceholder != "Current OAT" || oatSetPlaceholder != "")
            || (isaSetPlaceholder != "ISA" || isaSetPlaceholder != "") ) {
            print("there are values for everything")
            isTrue = false
        } else {
            print("there are no values")
            print("placeholder: \(elevPlaceholder)")
            isTrue = true
        }
        
        return isTrue
    }
    
}

#Preview {
    Pressure_DensityView()
}



I cannot reproduce on iOS 17.4. Clicking on the Takeoff and Landing Texts does dismiss the keyboard. Clicking right next to the text field also dismisses the keyboard. Please show a [mcve].

Next to it, like you said does actually work - but clicking above or below the texfield does not dismiss the keyboard
